# Mysql Select Query Clarification

Tags: mysql

I have a doubt on following query, please help me on this one,

```sql
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE (field_id  = 87 and value in ("xxxx")) AND (field_id = 88 and value in ("R"))
```

this results empty rows,
how to write this query i want to match id and value using "AND" condition

My table has values:

[image]

Comment: You need to use an `OR` in between your two conditions because `AND` will never satisfy and it will always give you 0 row. `(field_id  = 87 and value in ("xxxx")) OR (field_id = 88 and value in ("R"))`

Comment: @stud3nt I suspect that the OP intends to apply this logic across all records belonging to a single student.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh it could be a posibility. Thanks. @ ayyanar can you please clarify your requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you want here is all students who match both of the conditions.  One approach is to aggregate by student, and then assert the conditions:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING
    SUM((field_id, value) = (87, 'xxxx')) > 0 AND
    SUM((field_id, value) = (88, 'R')) > 0;
```

### Demo

Comment: is there any possibility to change your query to use "in" condition ?  like value in ('R','A')  currently it matches only value = 'R'

Comment: @ayyanarpms I might suggest opening a new question if you have other requirements.  I'm not inclined to start editing my answer here.

Comment: actually this question has that requirement only please check question, i ahve used in condition only for value